# Function that has two arguments and I can create a file into

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, f#-scripting

How can I define two functions in a given file system using f#script? A function that will have two arguments and will create a file into the root directory of the given file system. The first argument will be the name of the file and the second argument should be the file system.

Comment: For a good question, it is best to highlight which part you are stuck on.  In particular, it helps if you have a partial attempt with error messages or similar

Comment: [File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) will do this for you.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your Q?